# Empty user fields when using django allauth facebook provider

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-authentication, django-allauth

I'm using django and django-allauth. I can successfully authenticate a user using the facebook provider. The problem is that the created user object has all fields empty (first name, last name and email) and the username set to 'user' (which I assume is the default value for the generator). I also have a social account object associated with this user, which has the following data in the Extra data field:

```
{"name": "my_first_name my_second_name", "id": "my_uuid"}
```

I've checked overriding the SocialAccountAdapter [populate_user function](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py#L71) but the data parameter contains a dictionary where first name, last name and email are empty.

Searching up the code, in https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/base.py#L50 the response already comes with only

```
{"name": "my_first_name my_second_name", "id": "my_uuid"}
```

so I assume I have a configuration error of some sort with the Facebook provider.

My facebook settings:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'email',
            'public_profile',
            'user_friends'
        ],
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            #'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'
        },
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        #'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added FIELDS to settings as suggested by WizKid but no progress there

Comment: You could search Stackoverflow because this question is asked at least once every day. You need to specify which fields you want when you query Facebook.

Comment: @WizKid I did search before posting... I'm sorry if its a duplicate. I'll search again

Comment: the only similar question I could find was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326725/django-allauth-not-saving-custom-form I'll try the solution this afternoon and see if it works for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to v.023 from v.021 fixed the issue.